# How to set permissions to promote a file in Accurev

Tags: version-control, configuration, permissions, accurev

All,

We have had problems with engineers promoting files without the code being thoroughly tested and reviewed. They eventually ended up breaking the baseline. Instead of assuming the engineers will only promote their code after it has been reviewed and tested, I want to restrict their ability to promote until they are given permission to do so. For instance, after a code review, I would like to select the user/users and the file/files which they are allowed to promote. How can I automate this process?

How do the rest of you handle this "problem" of engineers deliberately or accidentally promoting files which end up breaking the baseline? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to address this.  The easiest one is to put a Lock on the destination stream that essentially says "Only a specific user or a specific group can promote to this stream".  This is done via point-and-click on a stream in the stream-browser.  So now you end up with a barrier to entry to that stream which is something you can control.  You can add additional layers of streams to supplement this approach as well.  For example, if you currently have:

Prod_Stream -- Build_Stream -- Workspaces

... you could now make it:

Prod_Stream -- Build_Stream -- Review_Stream -- Workspaces

Put the promote lock on Build_Stream so that they can break Review_Stream all they want but you keep a more pristine environment in Build_Stream.

It sounds like you are *not* using AccuRev Change Packages, the ability to link source files to issue records.  Those also become a powerful mechanism of control, where you can put constraints around promotion of those Change Packages, for example not allowing a Review to Build promotion unless the value of an issue field called "Status" has been toggled to "Passed Review".  Those then become programmatic controls, as opposed to manually implemented ones.

There are plenty of ways to skin the proverbial cat in AccuRev.  If you want more information, you could contact AccuRev Support or your specific account team to discuss alternatives.

Regards,
~James

Comment: Thanks. I will look at options that you mentioned.